How do I replace environment config for Angular app in Nx monorepo
Deployed my test app to firebase-hosting.
Clicking sign-up/sign-in button calls 'signInWithPopup(auth, provider)';
Popup window shows: "This site can’t be reached. 127.0.0.1 refused to connect."
I assume the reason for the error is the environment was not changed during the "build".
provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),

provideAuth(() => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    if (environment.useEmulators) {
        connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://127.0.0.1:9099');
    }
    return auth;
}),

We used to have "angular filereplacements" in Angular applications.
QUESTION: How do I replace environment config for Angular app in Nx monorepo?
The project.json file for the Angular app:
"targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/qubitme",
        "index": "apps/qubitme/src/index.html",
        ...
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          ...
          "outputHashing": "all"
        },
        "development": {
          "optimization": false,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },


please share package.json and angular.json, also command that runs for build, that is giving you this issue.

Hey @NarenMurali there are no scripts at all in the package.json and there's no 'angular.json' in the Nx monorepo. Instead there's a project.json file for each project/application in the monorepo. I'll update my question to share the 'build' executor. I assume that's what you're looking for, right?

You need to place the file replacement in each configuration you need in the project.json. https://angular.dev/tools/cli/environments#configure-environment-specific-defaults If you dont have it, you can create the environment by a cli command, which should do the stuff for you. works for nx and ng workspaces.

@ThomasRenger - I used to use those angular env files, but now I'm looking for an Nx type solution to this issue ( a project.json setting and/or and ".env" file).

This solution works for both, and for all builders. Angular additional provide env variable feature using define in your project files, additional you can check https://nx.dev/recipes/tips-n-tricks/define-environment-variables

Here is how i managed replacing env files within NX monorepo + Angular app:
project.json


"build": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/ngsf",
        "index": "apps/ngsf/src/index.html",
        "browser": "apps/ngsf/src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
        "tsConfig": "apps/ngsf/tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": ["apps/ngsf/src/assets"],
        "styles": [
          "apps/ngsf/src/styles.scss",
          "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
          "apps/ngsf/src/assets/styles/splash-screen.css"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "1mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "2kb",
              "maximumError": "4kb"
            }
          ],
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "libs/common/ui-common/src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "libs/common/ui-common/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "all"
        },
        "development": {
          "optimization": false,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },



Hope it works for you!

the solution you' ve provide would work for Webpack. I would like to implement this for ESBuild'. https://nx.dev/recipes/angular/use-environment-variables-in-angular#setting-the-define-option-of-the-application-executor
